in tweetnacl-rust Is there a way to Verify(detached_verify) signature on contract side in rust?
i saw TweetNacl-js library in Solana-Coookbook and if i want to sign signature in client side and sign the transaction and send it to solana smart contract.
Is there a way?
if i consider to use ED25519 Program..
how should i proceed?

Unfortunately, you can't call the ed25519 program directly from your smart-contract. You need to include an instruction to the program at the toplevel, ie:
        let privkey = ed25519_dalek::Keypair::generate(&mut thread_rng());
        let message_arr = b"hello";
        let mut instruction = new_ed25519_instruction(&privkey, message_arr);
        let mint_keypair = Keypair::new();

        let tx = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
            &[instruction.clone()],
            Some(&mint_keypair.pubkey()),
            &[&mint_keypair],
            Hash::default(),
        );

Copied from the rust tests at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/8f9fc2ada2396fc1e41a7393e9ac8714635d3107/sdk/src/ed25519_instruction.rs#L347
